# golang docker build for linux

Tags: docker

I need to compile a Golang application for Linux and I can't cross-compile under Mac, because of another library. So I decided to compile within a Docker container. This is my first time to use Docker.

This is my current directory structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Gopkg.lock
├── Gopkg.toml
├── Vagrantfile
├── bootstrap.sh
├── src
│   ├── cmd
│   │   ├── build.bat
│   │   ├── build.sh
│   │   ├── config.json
│   │   ├── readme.md
│   │   └── server.go
│   ├── consumers.go
│   ├── endpoints
│   │   ├── json.go
│   │   ├── rate.go
│   │   ├── test_payment.go
│   │   └── wallet.go
│   ├── middleware
│   │   └── acl.go
│   ├── models.go
│   ├── network
│   │   └── network.go
│   ├── qr
│   │   └── qr.go
│   ├── router
│   │   └── router.go
│   ├── service
│   │   └── walletService.go
│   ├── services.go
│   ├── setup.sql
│   ├── store
│   │   └── wallet.go
│   ├── stores.go
│   └── wallet
│       ├── coin.go
│       └── ethereum.go
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest 
WORKDIR /src/cmd
RUN ls
RUN go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
RUN go build -o main ./src/cmd/server.go 
CMD ["./main"]
```

I try to build the Docker image with:

```
docker build -t outyet .
```

This is the error it returns:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.505MB
Step 1/6 : FROM golang:latest
 ---> d0e7a411e3da
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /src/cmd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0c4c2b99e294
Step 3/6 : run ls
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 23d3e491a2e1
Step 4/6 : RUN go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
 ---> Running in f34447e51f6c
Removing intermediate container f34447e51f6c
 ---> 5731ab22ee43
Step 5/6 : RUN go build -o main server.go
 ---> Running in ecc48fcf5488
stat server.go: no such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c go build -o main server.go' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How i can build my Golang application with docker?

Comment: If you want to build the source code within Docker, you first have to copy the source code into your Docker image, which you're not doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're seeing is:

```
stat server.go: no such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c go build -o main server.go' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

... and in other words, it's telling you that the Go compiler can't find `server.go` which you're trying to build. Update your Dockerfile to copy your local files into the Docker image:

```
FROM golang:latest 
COPY . /go/src/workdir
WORKDIR /go/src/workdir
RUN go build -o main ./src/cmd/server.go 
CMD ["/go/src/workdir/main"]
```

In your directory I spotted `Gopkg.toml` which is a dependency manifest used by [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep). dep will use a directory called `vendor` to include all dependencies for your Go project. Before you build the Docker image, you need to ensure all dependencies are present with `dep ensure`:

```
$ dep ensure
$ docker build -t outyet .
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your sources in your build container. Add this line in your `Dockerfile` (after `FROM golang:latest` for example) :

```
ADD src/ /src/cmd
```

Then, you could access files inside the container (`/src/cmd`) : `RUN ls` should now return something.